# How to exclude "others" in my pie chart in Data Studio

Tags: pie-chart, looker-studio

I have a pie chart in Data Studio as below:

[image]

As you can see from the donut, there is "others" slice which I don't want to see it there, and I want to customize the label to show "python (88%)".

Can anyone share your expertise and enlighten me on how to do it?

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**

Following @Jaishree's suggestion, I have selected only the top 10, so there is no "others" now.

however, I still don't get it on how to show the label as "python (88%)"

As you can see, I have two fields in my data source (the table on the left): Category and TagsTotal. There is NO percentage_field.

To show "percentage", all I need to do is switch to "percentage" in the STYLE option:

[image]

What I ended up of creating this customized labeling is detailed below for future readers:

1. Back to the data source, create another field pctg:

`round((TagsTotal * 100 / (Select Sum(TagsTotal) From cte)),2) as pctg`

2. for the donut chart, create a new field named my_label

   CONCAT(category," (",pctg ,"% )")
3. add the new field my_label as the Dimension field
4. change in STYLE to show "label"

Voila!

[image]

Very cumbersome but finally kind of working with the rest to be sorted out:

**1. The newly created field is not showing up in the right-side panel as an available field and how to modify it?**

**2. The legend needs to be customized to display two lines instead of showing a pagina**

Comment: How did you do step 1 - get rid of "others"? I cannot achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Pie chart and donuts chart you can only show 20 slices. The chart shows the results in a sorted way. If you do not want to see others, then you have select only 20 data points.
2. "*python (88%)*" If you want to show the labels as "*python (88%)*" you can add a new field and customize the labels as you want.
   You can do that by click on "*create new field* " *then "add new field*" and then give a name to the new field in formula type the below code:

```
CONCAT(category," (",percentage_field,"% )")
```

To use the above formula you have to create a `percentage_field` also before, in the same way with percentage formula.

Comment: Thank you very much Jaishree, can you please check the UPDATE in the OP and advice more?

Comment: I understand the theory of point 1, but in practice, if I have a pie graph where the metric is "page views" how do I limit that data to 10 or 20 records when my page has 100s ?   I don't see how I can make this work for my graphs.  Can you confirm?

Comment: If Pie graph shows only top 20 values you can try some other graph to represent all the values